# Uninstalling Opencv 3 Alpha on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, uninstallation

I installed OpenCV 3 alpha on Ubuntu 14.04 a few months back and need to revert back to OpenCV 2.4.8 as my team is working on a **project in C++** using the same. I therefore would want to find a way to use both OpenCV 2.4.8 and OpenCV 3 simultaneously(i.e coexist) on the same system. I am also OK if I need to uninstall OpenCV 3 completely and then reinstall OpenCV 2.4.8.

I searched a lot on StackOverflow and AskUbuntu but am not able to find anything relevant to my case. Can somebody help me?

lsb_release -a gives

`No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty`

**Installation details**

 I installed OpenCV 3 alpha through downloading the source and installing it with the help of this link http://rodrigoberriel.com/2014/10/installing-opencv-3-0-0-on-ubuntu-14-04/

I had asked [this same question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/704883/uninstalling-opencv-3-on-ubuntu) on AskUbuntu a few days back but didn't get any suitable response.Please help!

Comment: [update-alternatives](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=linux+update+alternatives)

Comment: @bolov Can you please explain more? I am quite new to Ubuntu,that's why

Comment: I'm not familiar with update-alternatives. But I know it's a program that helps you manage multiple versions of the same program. It does that by making links to specific versions. For instance instead of `myprog` being the executable, it makes `myprog` a link to `myprov-v2.0` and makes it easy to swith between versions. OpenCV is a library, so you actually need to modify some env variables to make it work with multiple versions. Don't know if update-alternatives can manage that. That's why I just put a comment to a google search. I gave you something to investigate further.